# Get Product Collection based on brand parameter from cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, model, product-collection, custom-block

I'm creating custom block to get products based on the brand name

I'd like to pass the brand name parameter from the cms page like below

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/brand/brandprod_listing.phtml"  brand_name="mybrandname2"}}
```

However not sure how would i load my product collection in Block Model file dynamicallay receiving the `brand_name` parameter

Here is my model.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand','mybrandname');
```

However as can be seen, how to get the parameter passed from cms page and load the results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you:

```
{{block ... my_var="value here" ... template="catalog/brand/brandprod_listing.phtml"}}
```

**If you want to get the `my_var` in `php block` directly in `php block file` then try this:**

```
$my_var = $this->getMyVar();
```

Did you notice **capital `M` and `V`? This is magento default magic method.

**Or you simply want to display `$my_var` value in your `phtml` file `catalog/brand/brandprod_listing.phtml`**

```
$my_var = $this->getData('my_var');
```

For example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand', $my_var);
```

**Note**

Is attribute name is really `brand`? I believe it should be `manufacturer` for brands.

**[UPDATE 1]**

How are you calling `product collection`? Are you calling in `.phtml` file? If you are, I would suggest to call it in `block` files.

**[UPDATE 2]**

To have this `$my_var` in your model you need to call it from block.

1. In `.phtml` call a function

   ```
   $myProducts = $this->foo($my_var);
   ```
2. In `.php`, block file, write this function:

   ```
   public function foo($my_var)
   {
      $model = Mage::getModel('myExtension/myModel');
      return $model->getProductCollectionByBrand($my_var);
   }
   ```
3. and now in model file:

   ```
   public function getProductCollectionByBrand($my_var)
   {
      $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
      $_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand', $my_var);
      return $_productCollection;
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi
thanks, 
yes that's a custom attribute, name may vary later as I'd have to repeat for some other attributes too, just wanted to know the approach. 

I was aware of getData() however not sure how would that be available to model file

Comment: Yes I'm calling `product collection` in model file in its custom block folder

Comment: Remember, the $my_var is only accessible from .phtml and block files, not in model.

Comment: Yes that's the point
So that said I'll have to modify my model function to accept a parameter and pass that from block file correct ? 

`$products = Mage::getModel("brandproducts/brandproducts")->getBrandProducts($my_var);`

in 
// app/code/local/Mycomp/Brandproducts/Block/Brandproducts.php

Comment: oh! you already got it. :) BTW please check my updated answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Add bellow code in your file

```
app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/brand/brandprod_listing.phtml
```

**If your product attribute `brand` input type `text` then add bellow code.**

```
<?php $brand = $this->getBrandName();?>
<?php $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('brand',array('eq' => $brand));
?>
<?php 
    if(count($_productCollection)) {
        foreach($_productCollection as $product) {
            echo ($product->getName());
        }
    }
?>
```

**If your product attribute `brand` input type `select` then add bellow code.**

```
<?php $brand = $this->getBrandName();?>         
<?php
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');
$optionId = '';
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach($options as $option) {
        if (trim(strtolower($option['label'])) == trim(strtolower($brand))) {
            $optionId    = $option['value'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('brand',array('eq' => $optionId));
?>
<?php 
    if(count($_productCollection)) {
        foreach($_productCollection as $product) {
            echo ($product->getName());
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul, I was going with the same approach, however then i wanted to call collection in model file ( creating a custom block) 
so was not sure how to access $this->getData() in model file

Comment: when the .phtml file is not the part of custom block but just a simple file in template folder `/template/catalog/brand/brand_prod_listing.phtml` i cannot retrive variable data by `$this->getdata('brand_name')` or `$this->getBrandName()`

Comment: have you added brand_name in cms page???

Comment: yes i did for sure :) however it does not work with the phtml file only
and if i create a complete custom block and call the corresponding phtml file from backend then only getdata or getParaName works

Comment: can u share your complete code in qus??